filtering function not working on macbook. not with excel, not with command line, not with R
So I have this really simple dataframe of 20k rows and 6 columns, where last column is a number and I want to extract rows that contain only this number == 21. Very simple task. However, when I do the column filtering in excel it returns me with lots of rows that contains not only this number.
If I open the csv file with text editor it looks perfectly fine.
Gene,C,Z,Pval,FDR,Module
DNAH12,0.3628060037231064,617.990756638713,0.0,0.0,1.0
ABCA13,0.33464085936971066,569.9951132122194,0.0,0.0,1.0
PRB4,0.3353517120266698,566.667077873011,0.0,0.0,2.0
RP1,0.31793884623691454,544.7152358537128,0.0,0.0,1.0
CFAP299,0.3137380915326569,537.1739281421044,0.0,0.0,1.0

I switched to R. I got this.
     Gene         C        Z Pval FDR Module
1  DNAH12 0.3628060 617.9908    0   0      1
2  ABCA13 0.3346409 569.9951    0   0      1
3    PRB4 0.3353517 566.6671    0   0      2
4     RP1 0.3179388 544.7152    0   0      1
5 CFAP299 0.3137381 537.1739    0   0      1
6   DMBT1 0.3065342 518.7397    0   0      2
> table(df$Module)[22]
 21 
331 
> nrow(df[df$Module==21,])
[1] 20556

See? Supposedly I should have 331 items but now I have 20556. I then tried to extract it with linux command line. Simple code below. Then I got a new file with 2132 rows. Now I totally have no idea what's happening with my laptop. Today afternoon it was perfectly normal and then tonight it's this. I also tried restarting my laptop. Result remains the same. I'm utterly confused now why this is even happening...
grep '21.0' /Users/jiajia/Desktop/hotspot_results.csv > /Users/jiajia/Desktop/module21.csv

I'm using macbook 2018 Intel, system 13.6.6. Anyone ever encountered similar kind of issue before?

Can you edit your question to share the output of running dput(head(df$Module, 200))? I suspect the issue between 331 vs 2132 has to do with different matching thresholds; e.g. maybe 21.01 is counted as 21.0 in your linux count but in R that != 21, it'd be checking a numeric value to the ~15th decimal. I can't see yet what would cause the nrow line to be 20556, though.

do you have a lot of missing values when you do table(df$Module, useNA = 'ifany')

To expand on the comment by @rawr, when you do a logical comparison (like ==) and one side is missing (NA) then it returns an NA for the result.  When you use an NA for indexing, it returns an NA element or row.
Here is a quick and short example that shows this:
> mydf <- data.frame(x=1:5, Module=c(1, 21, 21, NA, NA))
> mydf[mydf$Module==21,]
      x Module
2     2     21
3     3     21
NA   NA     NA
NA.1 NA     NA

So while the count that we want is 2, the result has 4 rows because of the 2 rows with NA.  We can get the correct subset by checking for missing as well:
> mydf[!is.na(mydf$Module) & mydf$Module==21,]
  x Module
2 2     21
3 3     21

You can also see this by doing a table on the logical comparison:
> table(mydf$Module==21, useNA='ifany')

FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
    1     2     2 

Try either of the above with your data and see if that fixed your problem.

in the case of NA just use subset(mydf,Module==21)

Using subset if fine for interactive use, but there is a warning on the help page (?subset) that warns against using it when programming.  I have seen problems with using it as an argument to another function.
